# Functorial description of irreducibility of topological space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

A topological space is connected if it's not the coproduct of two non-trivial spaces. Equivalently, it is connected if the copresheaf it represents preserves coproducts.

A topological space is irreducible if it's not the union of proper closed subsets, or alternatively if every pair of non-trivial opens has inhabited intersection. Does irreducibility admit a functorial description?

Comment: By "coproduct" you mean disjoint union? Then the first statement is not true, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected yet not a disjoint union of any two non trivial spaces.

Comment: @freakish I think the OP means that coproduct of topological spaces, that is the disjoint union with the coproduct topology. In this case the statement is true because if a space is the *coproduct* (not just the disjoint union) of two subspaces, such subspaces are two disjoint open sets of the give space.